IPC dispatcher not strated MQL5 script
I'm working with the Python API of Meta Trader 5 and I have no access to the real server time from my broker, so I'm trying to create a script in MQL5 which reads the time using the existing functions, writing it in a file and then reading from my python code later on. The main issue I'm encountering is that the script doesn't seem to work at all despite compiling and being correctly code. I see an error message inside MT5 which says IPC failed to initialize IPC, with message: IPC dispatcher not started.
From what I have read online it is likely an error because the terminal is not initialized, yet I run my usual python code that should start MT5:
if not mt5.initialize():
    print("initialize() failed")
    mt5.shutdown()
mt5.login(login, password, server)

#Before calling my code using a subprocess:

try:
    result = subprocess.run([mt5_path, '/script', script_path], 
                            capture_output=True, 
                            text=True, 
                            check=True)
    
    # Parse the output
    output = result.stdout.strip()
    print(f"Raw output: {output}")
    
    #reading the last line of the output file
    text = open('D:\MetaTrader 5\MQL5\Files\market_watch_time.txt','r')
    lines = text.readlines()
    market_time = lines[-1]
    market_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(market_time)
    
    print(f"Market watch time: {market_time}")

except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print(f"Error running script: {e}")
    print(f"Script output: {e.output}")
except ValueError as e:
    print(f"Error parsing script output: {e}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An unexpected error occurred: {e}")

My MQL5 scripts looks pretty normal, so I assume I'm missing something?
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                           GetMarketWatchTime.mq5 |
//|                                  Copyright 2024, Your Name Here  |
//|                                             https://www.mql5.com |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#property copyright "Copyright 2024, Your Name Here"
#property link      "https://www.mql5.com"
#property version   "1.00"
#property script_show_inputs

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Script program start function                                    |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+



datetime GetMarketWatchTime()
{
    return TimeTradeServer();
}


void OnStart()
{
   datetime server_time = TimeTradeServer();
   Print("Server time: ", server_time);
   
   // Convert to string for easier handling in Python
   string time_str = TimeToString(server_time, TIME_DATE|TIME_SECONDS);
   Print("Server time (string): ", time_str);

   long unix_time = (long)server_time;
   Print(unix_time);  // This prints the Unix timestamp
   
   // Write the time to a file
   string filename = "market_watch_time.txt";
   int file_handle = FileOpen(filename, FILE_WRITE|FILE_TXT);
   if(file_handle != INVALID_HANDLE)
   {
      FileWriteLong(file_handle, unix_time);
      FileClose(file_handle);
   }
   else
   {
      Print("Error opening file: ", GetLastError());
   }
   
   // Terminate the MetaTrader 5 terminal
   TerminalClose(0);
}

Any ideas? Something I'm missing? How could I force/check the starting of the IPC? As I'm asking, does anyone know a better way to recover the data? There can't be a return on a void function so nothing better came to my mind.
